# How to run specific Jenkins Job for a large number of projects

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I'm a newbie in Jenkins and have some problems about how to configure it in order to run some specific Job (let's call it `code-check-syntax`) for a very large number of projects (repositories) from Gerrit. Let's say that all those projects have some kind of prefix and start from `abc` prefix, e.g.

- `abc/project1`
- `abc/project2`
- `abc/project3/subproject`
- ...

So, I'd like to run `code-check-syntax` Job for every patch-set created in any of those repositories.

P.S. It works for me good for a single repository (in Jenkins Freestyle type Job, SCM --> Git), but what if the number of repositories can be any. It seems to me that Jenkins [Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin) can be useful in this case, but can't figure out how to use it.

Comment: In my opinion the pipeline is intended for running a single repository. Ofcourse you can hack around that by hooking up multiple (git) projects to the same jenkins Jenkins build job. But then you have to use some plugin that will pass the repo url in the post data and parameterize this (I know that the gitlab webhooks do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time of researching, I found out that one can use **Gerrit parameters** provided to the build. In this particular case we can use `$GERRIT_PROJECT` parameter to address specific gerrit project.

[image]